# Parse data from csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I need some suggestion for an assignment I'm working on. So we are given a csv file with this format ,  as followed:

<0:100>, <1:1000> 
<1:1000>, <2:10000>

The task is to read the file, then perform BFS to find the lowest value node in the graph.

I'm thinking of constructing an adjacency list for the graph using python defaultdict(list) and apply BFS on the graph starting from node id 0.

For the construction of the adjacency list, I need to parse the data from the csv file to extract the node id and node value for each edge. What would be the most efficient way to do it in python?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the two values in the data (<0:100>)? If you want to find the lowest value node, assuming the second value is _the value_, why would you want to run BFS on that?

Answer (score 0):

The below code, will give an idea about parsing CSV file in python. Once you get the values in a object array, you can apply BFS based approach as a separate method.

```
nodes = []
line = 0
column = 0

try:
     f = open("nodes.txt")
     for nodelist in read_lines(f):
         line += 1
         column = 0
         for node in nodelist.split(","):
             nodeObject = {"nodeplace": "{0},{1}".Format(line,column), "value": node}
             column += 1
             nodes.append(nodeObject)   
     f.close()
except Exception:
     print("could not read file")

def read_lines(f):
     for line in f.readlines("\n")
         yield line

# To be defined: def max_value_using_bsf(nodes)
```